# Is there any property in data table widget that disables selecting the entire row in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to select only the checkbox instead of selecting the entire row in the data table widget in Flutter.

I have used the usual `onSelectChanged` function in the Data Row widget but it selects the entire row of the table in the data table widget in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **color** property in the *DataRow* widget to achieve what you are looking for.

Here is a sample code.

````
DataTable(
              columns: const [
                DataColumn(label: Text('C1')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('C2')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('C3')),
              ],
              rows: dataList.map((item) {
                return DataRow(
                    onSelectChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectionMap[item['id'].toString()] = value == true;
                      });
                    },
                    selected: _selectionMap[item['id'].toString()] ?? false,
                    color: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                        return Colors.transparent;
                      }
                      return null;
                    }),
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(item['id'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['name'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['age'].toString())),
                    ]);
              }).toList(),
            )
    ```
````